# Change UpdateSourceTrigger on Binding at Runtime

Tags: wpf, data-binding

Long story short, is there a programmatic way (in code behind) to create clone of an existing binding?

```
var internalTextBoxRef = RichTextEditor.FindName("mainRTB") as RichTextBox;
var bindingMarkup = MarkupWriter.GetMarkupObjectFor(internalTextBoxRef).Properties.FirstOrDefault(x => x.IsAttached);
var bindingBase = BindingOperations.GetBindingBase(internalTextBoxRef, bindingMarkup.DependencyProperty);
var b = bindingBase as Binding;

// Since you can't modify a binding that's already in use
// we need to clone, delete existing and attach a new modified one.
var newBinding = new Binding(b.Path.Path)
{
    ElementName = b.ElementName,
    UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
};

BindingOperations.ClearBinding(internalTextBoxRef, bindingMarkup.DependencyProperty);
BindingOperations.SetBinding(internalTextBoxRef, bindingMarkup.DependencyProperty, newBinding );
```

The above is what I am currently doing.  However, when I do this the control that uses this binding starts doing weird things like after every key press, the cursor goes to the start of the textbox.  I find it difficult to believe that simply changing the UpdateSourceTrigger would cause this so my instinct tells me there is something else in the original binding that is missing in the new one.  Looking in the debugger, the only thing that looks different is the 'Flags' property.  But the 'Flags' property cannot be set and I can't find any info that describes how the flags are generated.

Can anyone suggest some way to clone the original binding?

**Edit 1**

Here is my xaml binding:

```
<wpfRichText:RichTextEditor x:Name="RichTextEditor"
        Grid.Row="3" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,0,0,10" 
        IsContextMenuEnabled="True" IsToolBarVisible="True" IsReadOnly="False"
        Background="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlLightLightBrushKey}}"
        Foreground="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlTextBrushKey}}"
        Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=EmailerLayoutGrid}"
        BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.MenuBarBrushKey}}"
        Text="{Binding HtmlBodyText, Mode=OneWayToSource}" />
```

Adding UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged" to the Text binding does not do anything (which is why I am trying the shenanigans above).  If you are interested in the xaml of the control itself, you can find it [here](https://github.com/ngaillet/WPF-RichText-Editor/blob/master/src/WpfRichText/Controls/RichTextEditor.xaml).

**Edit 2**

So I have worked around this binding issue to get what I needed done. Unfortunately I had to break the MVVM paradigm to get it done.  Essentially I needed to have the binding update as the user types to enable a button so they could continue their workflow.  Unfortunately, the way the wpfrichtexteditor control is configured, you have to change focus to another control to cause the binding to update.  Since this control also accepts Tabs, you can't tab out of the control and cause an update.  You would have to navigate to another control.  The next control on the view I am working on is the button you would press in order to continue the workflow, which is disabled until the richtext binding updates.  So the user would have to use the mouse to click on a previous textbox to be able to proceed.  This is not acceptable usability IMO.

So I ended up doing the following in the code behind to get the desired behavior:

```
public partial class SomeUserControlView
{
    public SomeUserControlView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        CloseViewModelOnUnloaded = false;
        var internalTextBoxRef = RichTextEditor.FindName("mainRTB") as RichTextBox;
        internalTextBoxRef.TextChanged += OnTextChanged;
    }

    private void OnTextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs textChangedEventArgs)
    {
        var control = sender as RichTextBox;
        var doc = control.Document;

        var text = new TextRange(doc.ContentStart, doc.ContentEnd).Text;

        var viewModel = ViewModel as SomeUserControlViewModel;
        viewModel.HasBodyText = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text);
    }
}
```

My button is bound to a command that has a validation that checks, among other things, the HasBodyText property.

Comment: Can you show your Xaml binding declaration?

Comment: Please see Edit 1, thx.

Comment: Why not do it in a trigger in a Style? Set a flag property on the viewmodel.

Comment: After a quick inspection of the control's code I think that there is a bug and the behavior is not related to your code.

Comment: Ed:  My wpf is not that strong so I'm not sure I understand how your suggestion would work.  If you have the time to post an answer with a little snippet that shows a few more details about your solution, I'd be happy to try it.

Comment: Grx70:  Do you mean that the bug is causing this weird behavior when changing the binding?

Comment: @Bitfiddler Yes, as far as I can tell when the document of the inner `RichTextBox` is bound two-way, each user-originated change causes it to be converted to string and then back, causing the whole document to be reloaded, resulting in the caret returning to the beginning of the document. Thus, if you set `UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged`, this whole cycle is repeated every time the property changes.

Comment: Grx70: If you want to post your comments as the answer, I'd be happy to give credit.  The explanation gave a bit of relief that my ugly work around isn't entirely my fault ;-)